# Dictionary to List (C#)

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

Not really a problem, but I'm curious if there's a nicer way of doing this. Basically, I have a dictionary, where the key is a struct that I have created. What I need to do is get a list of a certain property in the keys. I.e. in the struct I have a field called 'ID', which I want to get a list of. What I'm doing now is this:

```
List<long> keys = new List<long>();
foreach(var key in dict.Keys)
{
     keys.Add(key.ID);
}
```

This works but I'm just wondering if I'm missing an even easier way - at first I thought perhaps the ToList method could be given a parameter so I can specify which part of the struct I want in the list, but it doesn't seem I can.

How would you guys improve this?

Comment: have you tried the LINQ .ToList() method?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Some good answers below, though! ^^

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
List<long> keys = dict.Keys.Select(k => k.ID).ToList();
```

Here you pass the ID to `Select()` rather than `ToList()`, and only call `ToList()` to convert the resulting collection to a list.

Comment: +1 @OP: FYI you don't need the ToList if you can make do with an IEnumerable<long>, i.e. if you are just iterating over it.

Answer (score 6):

Using [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) (From Linq) for the projection and [`ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) to create a concrete list. (Or [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) if you need to modify the resulting collection later)

```
var keys = dict.Keys.Select(k => k.ID).ToArray();
```

Comment: To be pedantic, `ToArray()` creates a `long[]` array rather than a `List<long>`.

Comment: Yes i was suggesting changing the resulting type actually :D `List<T>` have a slight overhead compared to `T[]` and when there is no reason to use the functionality it seem overkill to me to create an instance for nothing (As the backing store is a `T[]` internally anyway).

Answer (score 4):

Using Linq:

```
var keys = dict.Keys.Select(p => p.ID).ToList();
```

Using one of the constructors of `List`

```
var keys = new List<long>(dict.Keys.Select(p => p.ID));
```

(the constructor accepts an `IEnumerable<T>`, and the `Select` on `dict.Keys` clearly is it)

and using `AddRange`

```
var keys = new List<long>();
keys.AddRange(dict.Keys.Select(p => p.ID));
```

In general we are using the `.Select` "of" Linq to solve the problem. Clearly we could have written:

```
from p in dict.Keys select p.ID
```

instead of

```
dict.Keys.Select(p => p.ID)
```

I'll note the only interesting difference is for the `AddRange`: the other "ways" create a new `List` and fill it. `AddRange` adds to a preexisting `List` that could already have elements.

Comment: Except the keys are not longs.

Comment: @BoltClock Corrected all the examples

Answer (score 0):

use linq to return the ids as a list:

```
List<long> result = dic.Select(x => x.Key.ID).ToList();
```